# converting select list to php array using regex

Tags: regex

ok so I am trying to take a long select list formated like this:

```
            <option ringto="+93-" value="93">Afghanistan</option>

            <option ringto="+355-" value="355">Albania</option>

            <option ringto="+213-" value="213">Algeria</option>
```

and convert that to the following:

```
'Afghanistan' => '93',
'Albania' => '355',
'Algeria' => '213',
```

basically I am using a text editor to convert a select list for country codes (phone) to  php array. we are talking about 225 or so rows so manually is not an option heh..

how do I use regex to search/replace the patern:

```
<option ringto="+93-" value="{1}">{2}</option>
```

to

```
'{2}' => '{1}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for

```
^\s*<option ringto="[^"]*" value="(\d+)">([^<]*).*$
```

and replace all with

```
'\2' => '\1',
```

Let's hope you're using a text editor with Perl-compatible regular expression support.

Comment: yea that didn't work.. (I use textmate and I thought it was Perl-compatible..) looked further into it and found this: http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? The Oniguruma engine TextMate uses should work with this regex. Did you check the "Regular expression" checkbox in the Find dialog?

Comment: yea and it didn't work.  I ended up using this instead: <option ringto="(.*?)" value="(.*?)">(.*?)</option> and "$3" => "$1",